# Oracle SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH not working properly (always null)

Tags: oracle

I'm going mad with this strange behaviour.

I'm using 2 SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH queries, but one is always getting null, while I verified that there have values.

The objective is to join multiple rows in one, separated by commas.

This is the working one:

```
SELECT id_audit_req, SUBSTR(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (profs_names, ', ')), 3) all_descriptions
            FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id_audit_req ORDER BY id_audit_req, profs_names) rnum, id_audit_req, profs_names
                    FROM (SELECT id_audit_req, nvl(p.nick_name, p.name) profs_names
                            FROM audit_req_prof arp, professional p
                           WHERE arp.flg_rel_type = 'A'
                             AND arp.id_professional = p.id_professional
                          )
                  )
           START WITH rnum = 1
          CONNECT BY PRIOR rnum = rnum - 1 AND PRIOR id_audit_req = id_audit_req
           GROUP BY id_audit_req
```

With this query, the inner (before the SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH) SQl results are

```
rnum id_audit_req profs_names
   1            1 Auditor   
   1          501 Auditor   
   1          502 Auditor   
   2          502 Auditor2  
   1          503 Auditor   
   1          504 Auditor   
   1          505 Auditor   
   2          505 Auditor2
```

And the final result is right:

```
id_audit_req all_descriptions   
           1 Auditor           
         504 Auditor           
         502 Auditor, Auditor2
         505 Auditor, Auditor2
         503 Auditor           
         501 Auditor
```

Now I have another query, and the inner result is also right, but the final result is null, and I don't know why:

```
SELECT id_epis_triage, SUBSTR (MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (bp, ', ')), 3) all_descriptions
                            FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id_epis_triage ORDER BY id_epis_triage, bp desc) rnum, id_epis_triage, bp
                                    FROM (SELECT id_epis_triage, vsr.VALUE as bp
                                               FROM vital_sign_read vsr, vital_sign vs
                                              WHERE vsr.id_epis_triage in (SELECT arpe.id_epis_triage FROM audit_req_prof_epis  arpe
                                                                                 WHERE arpe.id_audit_req_prof = 2)
                                                AND vsr.flg_state = 'A'
                                                AND vsr.id_vital_sign IN (SELECT id_vital_sign_detail FROM vital_sign_relation WHERE relation_domain = 'C')
                                                AND vsr.dt_vital_sign_read in
                                                    (SELECT vsr2.dt_vital_sign_read
                                                       FROM vital_sign_read vsr2
                                                      WHERE (vsr2.id_epis_triage, vsr2.dt_vital_sign_read) IN
                                                            (SELECT id_epis_triage, MAX(vsr4.dt_vital_sign_read)
                                                            FROM alert.vital_sign_read vsr4
                                                           WHERE vsr4.id_epis_triage in (SELECT arpe.id_epis_triage FROM audit_req_prof_epis  arpe
                                                                                 WHERE arpe.id_audit_req_prof = 2)
                                                             AND vsr4.id_vital_sign = vsr.id_vital_sign
                                                             AND vsr4.flg_state = 'A'
                                                             group by id_epis_triage)
                                                        AND vsr2.id_vital_sign = vsr.id_vital_sign
                                                        AND vsr2.id_vital_sign IN (SELECT id_vital_sign_detail
                                                                                     FROM vital_sign_relation
                                                                                    WHERE relation_domain = 'C'
                                                                                      AND vsr2.id_epis_triage in (SELECT arpe.id_epis_triage FROM audit_req_prof_epis  arpe
                                                                                         WHERE arpe.id_audit_req_prof = 2)
                                                                                      AND id_vital_sign_parent = 28)
                                                        AND vsr2.flg_state = 'A')
                                                AND vs.id_vital_sign = vsr.id_vital_sign
                                                ORDER BY vs.intern_name_vital_sign
                                     )
                         )
                         START WITH rnum = 1
                         CONNECT BY PRIOR rnum = rnum - 1 and PRIOR id_epis_triage = id_epis_triage
                         group by id_epis_triage
```

Inner result:

```
rnum id_epis_triage  bp
   1           2134 120
   2           2134  85
   1           2137 112
   2           2137  98
```

Final result:

Null

Someone any idea? I've tried a lot of variations, almost always same result.
Only if I remove the START WITH clause, then I got this:

```
id_epis_triage all_descriptions
          2134 85              
          2137 98
```

This is, seems it is getting only the last value for each rnum.
But, essentially, both SQL are the same, the structure is exactly the same.

Comment: Are you getting a null for the `all_descriptions` for each ID, or a single row that has null, or no rows at all; or an error? You mentioned in a comment that you're on 10g and it seems related to the inner query length, which seems odd, so which client and version are you using, and do you see the same thing through SQL\*Plus (if that isn't what you're using now)?

Comment: Hi Alex. I'm getting no value at all, empty results (no rows). I'm using SQL Tools and SQL Developer to test the queries (both with the same result) and using Oracle Client 12.1.0 over a Win10 64x SO.
Executing the query on SQLPlus, same result (no rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work for me (I'm on 11.2.0.4):

```
WITH inner_result AS (SELECT 1 rnum, 2134 id_epis_triage, 120 bp FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 2 rnum, 2134 id_epis_triage, 85 bp FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 1 rnum, 2137 id_epis_triage, 112 bp FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 2 rnum, 2137 id_epis_triage, 98 bp FROM dual)
SELECT id_epis_triage,
       substr(MAX(sys_connect_by_path(bp, ', ')), 3) all_descriptions
FROM   inner_result
START  WITH rnum = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR rnum = rnum - 1
    AND    PRIOR id_epis_triage = id_epis_triage
GROUP  BY id_epis_triage;

ID_EPIS_TRIAGE ALL_DESCRIPTIONS
-------------- ----------------
          2137 112, 98
          2134 120, 85
```

What version are you on and does the above query (as-is, including the inner_result subquery) work for you too?

Comment: Hi. You query also works for me (I'm in Oracle 10.2). It must be another reason. Maybe the length of the query?

Comment: It's really difficult to diagnose your issue without the underlying tables, data, etc. One thing you could try is putting "rownum" into the select list of the top query in the inner query (e.g. `SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id_epis_triage ORDER BY id_epis_triage, bp desc) rnum, id_epis_triage, bp, rownum`); that should ensure the inner query is done before the outer query. Give that a go, and see if that helps.

Comment: S**t, it is that!!! The length of the query makes it fail!! How can this be true? :(
I tested a less subquery length and it is working properly.
@Boneist thanks for your time, I tested the ROWNUM tip but still not working with a big subquery. Only if I do a shorter query, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

So, the final problem was... the subquery seems to be so big and SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH doesn't work properly (at least in my Oracle 10.2 version).

So I refined the SQL subquery to do a similar result but with less text, and this was the result:

```
SELECT id_epis_triage, SUBSTR (MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (bp, ', ')),3) all_descriptions
                            FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id_epis_triage ORDER BY id_epis_triage, bp desc) rnum, id_epis_triage, bp
                                    FROM    (SELECT id_epis_triage, vsr.VALUE as bp
                                               FROM vital_sign_read vsr, vital_sign vs
                                              WHERE vsr.flg_state = 'A'
                                                AND vsr.id_vital_sign = vsr.id_vital_sign
                                                AND vs.id_vital_sign = vsr.id_vital_sign
                                                AND vsr.id_vital_sign IN (SELECT id_vital_sign_detail
                                                                                     FROM vital_sign_relation
                                                                                    WHERE relation_domain = 'C'
                                                                                      AND id_vital_sign_parent = 28)
                                                AND (vsr.id_epis_triage, vsr.dt_vital_sign_read) IN
                                                     (SELECT id_epis_triage, MAX(vsr4.dt_vital_sign_read)
                                                        FROM vital_sign_read vsr4
                                                       WHERE   vsr4.flg_state = 'A'
                                                         AND vsr4.id_epis_triage in (SELECT arpe.id_epis_triage FROM audit_req_prof_epis arpe WHERE arpe.id_audit_req_prof = 2)
                                                        group by id_epis_triage
                                                     )
                                              ORDER BY vs.intern_name_vital_sign
                                     )
                         )
                         START WITH rnum = 1
                         CONNECT BY PRIOR rnum = rnum - 1  and prior id_epis_triage = id_epis_triage
                         group by id_epis_triage;
```

Really a weird problem, but thanks to @Boneist I look for this alternative.

```
id_epis_triage all_descriptions
          2134 120, 85         
          2137 112, 98
```